# Generic Constructors and Inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

I have a generic class with a class constraint on it.

```
public class MyContainer<T> where T : MyBaseRow
```

MyBaseRow is an abstract class which I also want to contain a member of some flavour of MyContainer.

```
public abstract class MyBaseRow
{
    public MyContainer<MyBaseRow> ParentContainer;

    public MyBaseRow(MyContainer<MyBaseRow> parentContainer)
    {
        ParentContainer = parentContainer;
    }
}
```

I am having problems with the constructors of classes inherited from MyBaseRow eg.

```
public class MyInheritedRowA : MyBaseRow
{
    public MyInheritedRowA(MyContainer<MyInheritedRowA> parentContainer)
    : base(parentContainer)
    { }
}
```

Won't allow MyInheritedRowA in the constructor, the compiler only expects and only allows MyBaseRow. I thought the generic class constraint allowed for inheritance? What am I doing wrong here and is there any way I can redesign these classes to get around this?
Many thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: MyContainer is a container of MyBaseRow. And MyBaseRow has a reference to MyContainer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you can't use generics that way, because the covariance system doesn't work that way *with classes*. See here: http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2010/01/10/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-4.0.aspx

You *can* however use an interface like this:

```
public interface MyContainer<out T> where T : MyBaseRow {

    }
```

And that code will compile.

Comment: Problem solved - I had no idea you could use an interface like this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a covariant generic interface (C#4.0):

```
  public interface IContainer<out T> where T : MyBaseRow
  {

  }

  public class MyContainer<T> : IContainer<T> where T : MyBaseRow
  {

  }

  public abstract class MyBaseRow
  {
    public IContainer<MyBaseRow> ParentContainer;

    public MyBaseRow(IContainer<MyBaseRow> parentContainer)
    {
      ParentContainer = parentContainer;
    }
  }

  public class MyInheritedRowA : MyBaseRow
  {
    public MyInheritedRowA(IContainer<MyInheritedRowA> parentContainer)
      : base(parentContainer)
    { }
  }
```

Comment: I marked aquinas response as my accepted answer simply because he responded first but I really appreciate your spelling it out for me using my example. It really helped. Cheers.